# In Haskell, how do I decode a JSON value that could be of two different types?

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, aeson

I'm trying to parse some bibliographic data, more specifically, pull out the 'subject' field for each item. The data is json and looks something like this:

```
{"rows": [

      {"doc":{"sourceResource": {"subject": ["fiction", "horror"]}}},
      {"doc":{"sourceResource": {"subject": "fantasy"}}}
]}
```

I can pull out 'subject' if every entry is either Text or [Text], but I'm stumped as to how to accommodate both. Here is my program in its current state:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings#-}
import Debug.Trace
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import Network.HTTP.Conduit (simpleHttp)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict  as HM
import qualified Data.Map as Map

jsonFile :: FilePath
jsonFile = "bib.json"

getJSON :: IO B.ByteString
getJSON = B.readFile jsonFile


data Document = Document { rows :: [Row]}
              deriving (Eq, Show)


data Row = SubjectList [Text]
         | SubjectText Text
         deriving (Eq, Show)


instance FromJSON Document where
  parseJSON (Object o) = do
    rows <- parseJSON =<< (o .: "rows")
    return $ Document rows
  parseJSON _ = mzero


instance FromJSON Row where
  parseJSON (Object o) = do
    item <- parseJSON =<< ((o .: "doc") >>=
                           (.: "sourceResource") >>=
                           (.: "subject"))
    -- return $ SubjectText item
    return $ SubjectList item
  parseJSON _ = mzero

main :: IO ()
main = do
   d <- (decode <$> getJSON) :: IO (Maybe Document)
   print d
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

the working FromJSON Row instance:

```
instance FromJSON Row where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    (SubjectList <$> (parseJSON =<< val)) <|>
    (SubjectText <$> (parseJSON =<< val))
    where
      val = ((o .: "doc") >>=
             (.: "sourceResource") >>=
             (.: "subject"))
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, look at the type of

```
((o .: "doc") >>=
 (.: "sourceResource") >>=
 (.: "subject")) :: FromJSON b => Parser b
```

We can get out of it anything that's an instance of [`FromJSON`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t%3aFromJSON). Now, clearly, this can work for `Text` or `[Text]` individually, but your problem is that you want to get either `Text` *or* `[Text]`. Fortunately, it should be fairly easy to deal with this. Rather than letting it decode it for you further, just get a [`Value`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t%3aValue) out of it. Once you've got a `Value`, you could decode it as a `Text` and put it in a `SubjectText`:

```
SubjectText <$> parseJSON val :: Parser Row
```

Or as a `[Text]` and put it in a `SubjectList`:

```
SubjectList <$> parseJSON val :: Parser Row
```

But wait, either one of these will do, and they have the same output type. Notice that [`Parser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t%3aParser) is an instance of [`Alternative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t%3aAlternative), which lets us say exactly that (“either one will do”). Thus,

```
(SubjectList <$> parseJSON val) <|> (SubjectText <$> parseJSON val) :: Parser Row
```

Ta-da! <sup><sub>(Actually, it wasn't necessary to pull it out as a `Value`; we could have instead embedded that long `((o .: "doc") >>= (.: "sourceResource") >>= (.: "subject"))` chain into each subexpression. But that's ugly.)</sub></sup>

Comment: I should note that these type annotations on each expression are not necessary, but only for clarity here. You should omit them in your actual code.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is exactly what I needed, though I had to make a modification, namely:
 (SubjectList <$> parseJSON =<< val) <|>
 (SubjectText <$> parseJSON =<< val)

Comment: @reklak: You should be able to omit the `=<<` if you use `do` notation and have `val <- ...` rather than `let val = ...` above it.